# Go address of array element

Tags: go

How do I get the address of an array element in Go?

Comment: the memory address or the index?

Comment: the memory address. what in C would be the array address + index

Comment: See https://golang.org/doc/faq#no_pointer_arithmetic

Comment: I doubt you can add extra characters to an array. An array has fixed size.

Comment: I know that there's no pointer arithmetic. But I still need the address to store it in another container.

Comment: I meant add extra characters to the question.

Comment: Re: "I don't find the documentation at all concise" -- sorry, but with the amount of low-level understanding you're seeking in your questions, you need to be willing to at least refer to [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec), ideally study it. We're not talking about a C++14-sized whale of a doc here.

Comment: I've been asking these questions because I needed trivial answers to things that the document on Go I was reading obfuscates too much, makes too verbose, and makes me waste too much time finding these trivial answers. But I was evidently reading the wrong document, which isn't really the spec, but a more verbose 'walkthrough' of Go: [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html). Thanks to your link I now have the document that I need

Comment: Also, this question will server as a reference to a programmer coming from C who quickly needs this 'recipe', since it isn't natural for someone who would normally use pointer arithmetic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [address operator &](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) to take the address of an array element. Here's an example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    p := &a[3]     // p is the address of the fourth element

    fmt.Println(*p)// prints 4
    fmt.Println(a) // prints [1 2 3 4 5]
    *p = 44        // use pointer to modify array element
    fmt.Println(a) // prints [1 2 3 44 5]

}
```

Note that the pointer can be used to access the one element only. It's not possible to add or subtract from the pointer to access other elements.